# Is there a way to force my website's users to use 2-step verification when they signin on my website with Google Identity platform?

Tags: authentication, google-plus, google-identity

I have a website where users can sign in with Google login. I would like to force some of them (who wish to better protect their account on my website) to sign-in with 2-step login even they haven't activated it for Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force 2-step verification and cannot sign the user out of Google, forcing them to sign back in using 2-step, using the Google+ API or Identity platform.